# Spurious tokens don't raise typescript errors

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this raise a syntax error?

```
class foo {
    public x = 42;    comment
}
```

or even stranger

```
class foo2 {
    comment_wtf
    extra_weird
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are properties of type `any`. The semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the line.

Comment: @Ray Properties are automatically created upon first assignment in JavaScript. There is no need to generate code that declares them upfront.

Comment: Why is it weird that static type information which is not applicable in the target language is not generated?

Comment: Why is it weird??  Look at it. Just LOOK at it.  Understandable: maaaaybe.  Weird: oh yes, most definitely--with bacon.

Comment: Also, it doesn't have to be this weird.  Since classes are not a JS thing, TS could simply drop the auto semicoloning in classes, and the weirdness would be gone.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by rightfold these are just member properties of the class you are declaring. If you use an undeclared member you *will get an error as shown below*:

```
class Foo {
    comment_wtf
    extra_weird
}

var foo:Foo;
foo.comment_wtf = 'allowed';
foo.notThere = 'error'; // ERROR
```